# Time out error when using browser.getCurrentUrl() after URL changes

Tags: protractor, assertion

I am writing a protractor test for login for an AngularJS app and want to verify that the login is successful and the url changes after login. I tried to use Expected condition with urlContains() and also tried with browser.getCurrentUrl().toContain() but I am getting error in both.

```
exports.config = {

    seleniumAddress : 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', 
    specs: ['login.spec.js'],

    };
```

Expected condition passes the test when the url is correct. But when the url is different then it throws timeout error 
"Failed: Wait timed out after 5013ms".
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('/dashboard') fails always with below error

```
Stack:
    ScriptTimeoutError: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds
      (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
    Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
    System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.3', java.version: '12.0.1'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
        at parseHttpResponse (/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
        at doSend.then.response (/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    From: Task: Protractor.waitForAngular()
        at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:807:17)
        at ProtractorBrowser.executeAsyncScript_ (/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:425:28)
        at angularAppRoot.then (/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:456:33)
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1376:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
        at asyncRun (/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27)
        at /Users/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    From: Task: Run it("should login successfully") in control flow
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/Users/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ProtractorTest/Tests/login.spec.js:17:3)
        at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at /Users/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:93:5
```

Below is my code

```
it('should login successfully', function () {
  browser.get("https://example.com/");
  loginobj.username.sendKeys(logindata.email);
  loginobj.password.sendKeys(logindata.password);
  loginobj.loginbtn.click().then(function(){
  browser.getCurrentUrl().then(url => expect(url).toContain('/dashboard'));
  //var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  //browser.wait(EC.urlContains('/dashboard'), 5000);  
})
```

I expect that when the url is different than the expected one, it should display a valid error message instead of timeout error.

Comment: Try to do `expect(true).toBe(true)` and please tell me if it fails. Just want to eliminate webdriver issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default protractor handles all the asynchrony for you. Looking at your code you are relying on default protractor behaviour i.e. not setting `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER` to `false`.

In that case, why do you want to do something inside `click().then()` ? It can be as simple and plain as

`loginobj.loginbtn.click();
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('/dashboard');`

One theory with your code: once you have something inside `click().then()`, its out of place from the promise queue that protractor is handling for you. Unless it is absolutely necessary, for ex get value from an element for later use in the spec, I would suggest not to meddle with protractor asynchronous handling as much as possible.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar

```
const currentUrl = await browser.getCurrentUrl().then(url => url);
expect(currentUrl).toContain('/dashboard')
```

Try it out maybe it will help, just without await as i see you don't use async functions

or like this

```
await browser.getCurrentUrl().then(url => expect(url).toContain('/dashboard'));
```

Comment: I updated the test as below. But I am getting "Unexpected identifier" error ```it('should login successfully', async () => { browser.get("https://pdtest.gan-compliance.com/"); loginobj.username.sendKeys(logindata.email); loginobj.password.sendKeys(logindata.password); loginobj.loginbtn.click().then(()=> { const currentUrl = await browser.getCurrentUrl().then(url => url); await expect(currentUrl).toContain('/dashboard') });```

Comment: Do it without awaits as you mix 2 approaches in one it, also
try something like this
`browser.getCurrentUrl().then(url => expect(url).toContain('/dashboard'));`
if you use async function then you have to use in every loginobj step await

Comment: i tried without await and also tried with using aync and await. I am getting the error "Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds and gives build Info, System info and Driver info: driver.version: unknown." in both the cases

Comment: @jane Can you provide more information from stacktrace about error, also about application you are testing. Is it angular/other fw, also your protractor conf would be nice to see. Please edit main post for that. At first i thought that maybe it's a fault of protractor sync but it seems something different.

Comment: Updated the post. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

In protractor default script time out is 11 seconds,
In above code snippet,

```
browser.getCurrentUrl().then(url => expect(url).toContain('/dashboard'));
```

statement takes more than 11 seconds to resolve promise.

**Solution**: In Protractor configuration file, add below statements
`allScriptsTimeout: timeout_in_millis`.
e.g for 30 second timeout

```
allScriptsTimeout: 30000
```

**Edited Configuration File:**

```
exports.config = {
allScriptsTimeout: 30000,
seleniumAddress : 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', 
specs: ['login.spec.js'],
```

};

Comment: I added allScriptsTimeout: 30000, in config file, but i still get the time out error.It doesn't take long to login. Looks like it is not getting the URL for some reason. I get the error 'Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 30 seconds'

Comment: Are you trying to automate non anguler website using protractor?

Comment: it is an angular website.

Comment: Refer below link for all type of timeouts in protractor. Link: https://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts. It may be helpful.